# What is this plant and is it safe around toddlers?

Tags: identification

I wondered what kind of plant this is and whether it's ok to have in the garden with a toddler. It was quite soft when it started growing but now seems to be covered in a fuzz that stings the skin.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one of the *Pulmonaria*. There are many cultivars. I think you should wait for the flowers, to see which one it is.

Tell your toddler not to touch any plant. As far I know, this is not dangerous, but you know the children: so maybe you should plant some bitter plant (but not toxic), so that your children learn not to eat from plants (if it is not a plant in your garden, it is a plant somewhere else).